# Fetch ID value from given JSON

Tags: regex, curl

How can I get the value of id from given sample below..

```
{ "photoId": { "id": "CAoSLEFGMVFpcE5tbW82VTNhZ210ZDlLQ0J4dTEtNk5nZlNTV25CeXhzTHJxZ3Rk" } }
```

I am getting this value from

```
$response_meta = curl_exec($curl_meta);
```

I want the result

```
CAoSLEFGMVFpcE5tbW82VTNhZ210ZDlLQ0J4dTEtNk5nZlNTV25CeXhzTHJxZ3Rk
```

and store in avriable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to access it the following way.

```
$response_meta['photoID']['id']
```

Comment: try json_decode($response_meta) and then access it the way I mentioned.

Comment: When i use echo $response-meta ; Its giving result 1

Comment: Thank you .Solved

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `$response_meta.photoId.id` or `$response_meta['photoId']['id']`

```
var $response_meta = { "photoId": { "id": "CAoSLEFGMVFpcE5tbW82VTNhZ210ZDlLQ0J4dTEtNk5nZlNTV25CeXhzTHJxZ3Rk" } };
console.log($response_meta.photoId.id);
console.log($response_meta['photoId']['id']);
```

Here is a plunker: [Get the id from the object](http://plnkr.co/edit/E0yPYXT9tuwq8kqrKrlj?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I did by this way
first set

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
$response_meta = curl_exec($curl_meta);

$response_json = json_decode($response_meta, true);
$response_result = var_dump($response_json['photoId']['id']);
```

It gave me the result

```
string(64) "CAoSLEFGMVFpcE9pNkhOUmI0X2ZSQTJaUkM0ZFVMa1U4Q25hWEUwbEtKY3VGNm9J"
```